# Moving value in front of dictionary inside dictionary as key/value

Tags: python, dictionary

can anyone help me with adding the numbers in front of the ":" (1, 11014, 11019) as a key/value inside the list of dictionaries? I can't seem to figure out how to access it. Thank you!

```
df = {1: [{'Weekday': 'Sunday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 9.0,
   'Duration': 0.0},
  {'Weekday': 'Monday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 17.0,
   'Duration': 8.0}],
 11014: [{'Weekday': 'Sunday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 9.0,
   'Duration': 0.0},
  {'Weekday': 'Monday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 17.0,
   'Duration': 8.0}],
 11019: [{'Weekday': 'Sunday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 9.0,
   'Duration': 0.0}]}
```

I would want something like:

```
df = [{'Id' : 1,
'Weekday': 'Sunday',
   'StartTime': 9.0,
   'EndTime': 9.0,
   'Duration': 0.0} 

...]
```

I tried this:

```
for i in df:
    i['UserId'] = i 
print(df)
```

Comment: Where do you want to move it?  Can you give an example of what you want the final result to be?

Comment: There are three lists of dictionaries, which one do you want to modify? It also looks like you are trying to put each dictionary inside of itself with the `i['UserId'] = i`. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Samwise I included what I would want in the question! I just want the "Id" that is in front (1, 11014, 11019) inside the dictionary

Comment: `df` is just a dictionary. It sounds like you want to create a list of dictionaries *from* it (or turn it into one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by iterating through your key and values like this:

```
output_list = []
for k, v_list in df.items():
    for v in v_list:
        v['id'] = k
        output_list.append(v)
```

EDIT: since your values are in list